How to get entities and their values in DialogFlow ES
New to DialogFlow. So, I have created a flow which asks the user for their name, email and dob and at the end of dob I have enabled fulfillment which makes an api call to my flask server. Here, I need to get all the 3 data above so I can store them in my SQL DB but I am unable to fetch entities. What is the correct way to do it? How do I get entities?
I had a look at this Dialogflow Get entities
But I could not get it/understand correctly.
Any help would help greatly. Thank you all.

Could you please clarify more , are you not able to fetch entities data in Dialogflow Es or you are able to get those entities in dialogflow ES but not able to store it in your SQL DB .
If  you want to know how to get entities in Dialogflow ES , You can take a look at this document  How to enable and use developer entities in Dialogflow  . Let me know if this helps or not .

Hello, thank you for replying, I have given a https link as fulfilment link and it calls my python backend, but I do not know how to get hold of entities. At the end of the convo, I would like to save everything in db. But I am not able to fetch it from dialogFlow.

Hi , as you are using python to get entities,can you look at this stack ans to get entities in python env . Let me know if this helps to you or not .

If you're using the Inline Editor for Fulfillment, you can use the following syntax to index to your parameters:
agent.parameters.paramName

Replace "paramName" with the name of your created parameter
Be sure to use preview pane on the right of the Dialogflow dashboard to test your intents and ensure that your messages are being picked up as their relevant entities respectively.

I am not using inline editor, I am using DialogFlow api in python. Any way I can get entities there?
